# Howto enable Ligatures for mono fonts in xfce4-terminal

Tags: fonts, xfce4-terminal

As the title says, how can I enable ligatures in xfce4-terminal? I can't find any info on this in the manual.

Comment: I do not think mono fonts have ligatures at all.And as ligatures are actually different symbols you can reach the situation where you can't execute a command

Comment: There are quite a few mono fonts having ligatures, like Fira Code Mono for example

Answer (score 5):

Terminals based on libvte do not support ligatures.
There is a good list of supported terminals and editors at https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#terminal-compatibility-list